# Chrome - blackbox a script - no menu item

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to blackbox a script (as mentioned here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing ) but I don't see that as an option when I right click on the file in the left hand Sources panel (Navigator).

Nor do I see any mention of it in Settings.

Any suggestions?

I'm using

```
Google Chrome   48.0.2540.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)
Revision    37d6b63597f41322f6092405ae913b19a7e85686-refs/heads/master@{#354704}
```

Comment: I'm noticing this as well.. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click **WITHIN** the editor of the script that you want to blackbox, and **NO LONGER** on the actual file name in the navigator panel. The option is on the bottom of "that" context menu. (image below)

I know this is a bit old and was just about to add a comment that I couldn't find it either, but I lucked out. Using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m. Hope this helps.

[image]